# R sort data, but exclude blank rowname

Tags: r, regex

I have a set of data with rownames which that hold 2 sets of data as the name, separated by a comma. Is there a way to sort for a blank word and return only that row?

*Edited as there are more than two entries in the data and the previous answers don't extend beyond two entries

```
z <- c("apple,new,tree")
z <- rbind(z,"apple,new")

z[grep(paste0(",","",".*"),z)]
```

## Output

```
> z[grep(paste0(",","",".*"),z)]
[1] "apple,new,tree" "apple,new"
```

## Desired Output

```
> z[grep(paste0(",","",".*"),z)]
[1] "apple,new"
```

Comment: Maybe [`grep("^[^,]*,$",z,value = TRUE)`](https://ideone.com/nOhVQT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it without regular expressions:

```
> z[sapply(strsplit(z,","),length)==1]
[1] "apple,"
```

On edit:  here's a more general solution that should work for any such dataset, provided that the commas are in the right places.

```
z <- "apple,new,tree"
z <- c(z,"apple,new,")
z <- c(z,"apple,,tree")

z[sapply(strsplit(paste0(z,","),","),function(x) any(x==""))]
[1] "apple,new,"  "apple,,tree"
```

If you have missing commas at the end of some entries, it gets more complicated, but you get the idea.

Comment: This worked for 2 entries, but I just realized that there are more than two, and this returns `character(0)` when it runs on more than 2